# facebook invite not getting deleted

Tags: php, facebook

I'm using facebook function to delete an invite from notifications and application page tab after the invite is accepted but it is giving me a error.

```
       function build_full_request_id($request_id, $user_id) {
      echo $request_id . '_' . $user_id; 
      }

    foreach ($request_ids as $request_id)
   {
    ("reqeust_id=".$request_id."<br>");
    $full_request_id = build_full_request_id($request_id, $user_id);  
   ("full_request_id=".$full_request_id."<br>");

  try {
     $delete_success = $facebook->api("/$full_request_id",'DELETE');
     if ($delete_success) {
        echo "Successfully deleted " . $full_request_id;}
     else {
       echo "Delete failed".$full_request_id;}
    }          
  catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
   "error";}
}
```

This is the error,i get **Call to a member function api() on a non-object in**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow, you have so many errors in your "code" i wonder that it only fails with the non-object  error. try this one:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '1231231231231',
  'secret' => '12ba5212bae2617267',
));


foreach ($request_ids as $request_id)   {
    $full_request_id = $request_id."_".$user_id;  

    try {
      $delete_success = $facebook->api('/'.$full_request_id, 'DELETE');
      if ($delete_success) {
          echo "Successfully deleted ".$full_request_id;
      }else{
          echo "Delete failed ".$full_request_id;
      }
    } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error means that your variable `$facebook` is not an object.  Find the place in your code where `$facebook` is created and make sure you are generating it correctly.  It should look something like this:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '1231231231231',
  'secret' => '12ba5212bae2617267',
));
```

(Obviously, it should have your appId and secret rather than the junk ones I put in there.)